# What are the .pgAdmin4.2123502176.addr and .log files?

Tags: log, pgadmin-4

I recently installed pgAdmin4 on Win 10 64-bit. At the top of my main User directory it makes two tiny files, .pgAdmin4.2123502176.addr and .pgAdmin4.2123502176.log. (I'm assuming the numbers change over time...)  The .addr file says:

> http://127.0.0.1:1913/?key=4f8ced45-3edf-4583-a39d-3579........

The .log file began today empty, but it does collect errors - a lot of these:

> error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

And some real errors I've seen in the Admin program console.

All I find on the web is that logs are in:

> "C:\Users**\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin"

There is a pgadmin4.log there, which has errors going back to installation, but not the multiple [Errno 10053] from today. It does have the console errors from today.

So: Why are these files in my main User directory?

Why isn't anyone talking about them?

Can I move them somewhere else?